# express.js serving both static content and RESTful services?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, express

I am currently using [serve-static](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-static) to serve up a very static Angular single page application (SPA), but now need to expand to my SPA to be able to also load/change dynamic data from the server.

From my research, I thinking the best approach might be to replace the existing "serve-static" module with express.js, which should allow me to augment the backend with a RESTful service (which would then in turn provide the access to data as required).

Since I don't have too much experience in this and because architectural questions are not easily googleable, I had following questions: 
- Can express.js serve both static and RESTful services simultaneously? If so, is this a proven approach or are there better methods? 
- Or should I be running a separate service (lighttpd) for my REST api? Can they co-exist?

This will be running in an embedded Linux environment, so the amount of traffic is minimal, I'm thinking max 2-3 users simultaneously, more typically one user at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it can do both. Just put your static middleware near the top of your middleware stack and put all of your routes below that. That way if a static file isn't found at the requested path, execution will continue to the routes you have defined.

Comment: So I might consider doing something like this, right?    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));app.get('/data',function(req,res){ ...} (sorry, can't seem to edit nicely in comments)

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to validate this yesterday!